# Unable to create s3 bucket using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to create a **aws** bucket from **python3** using **boto3**. `create_bucket()` is the method I use. Still I get an error `botocore.errorfactory.BucketAlreadyExists`

**MY CODE:**

```
import boto3

ACCESS_KEY = 'theaccesskey'
SECRET_KEY = 'thesecretkey'

S3 = boto3.client('s3', 
                   aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY, 
                   aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_KEY)

response = S3.create_bucket(Bucket='mynewbucket',
           CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint':'ap-south-1'})
```

**ERROR:**

```
botocore.errorfactory.BucketAlreadyExists: An error occurred (BucketAlreadyExists) 
when calling the CreateBucket operation: The requested bucket name is not available. 
The bucket namespace is shared by all users of the system. 
Please select a different name and try again.
```

However, the Bucket does not exist and it still failed to create the bucket.

**EDIT**

I found the reason from the [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/899704/aws-s3-bucket-name-already-exists) and I also posted that in answers in-order to help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I got it after reading few articles on-line. The bucket name should be **globally unique** once it satifies that condition it works as I expect. 

I share this to help someone wonders just like me

[Reference](https://serverfault.com/questions/899704/aws-s3-bucket-name-already-exists)